# How to center an absolute paragraph inside a relative div

Tags: html, css, alignment, center, paragraph

I want to center a paragraph which is positioned absolute inside another div positioned relative. The  problem is since this is absolute I can't use text-align: center! Also I want to center the paragraph both vertically and horizontally.. .
My HTML looks like this

```
<div class="top">

    <p class="same">Django</p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.top
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
}
.same
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

I want the paragraph text 'Django' to be in the center both vertically and horizontally
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXPJ5.jpg)

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: .same { position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:center; }. This way you could use text-align: center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need absolute positioning at all to achieve what you want :

```
.top { width: 100%; height: 70px; text-align: center; }
.same { display: inline; line-height: 70px; }
```

You can force paragraphs to have `inline` layout and then center them horizontally using `text-align: center`. To center them vertically just add `line-height` to paragraph equal to container's `height` (it is not a problem here as you container's height is fixed). If you don't want to set `display: inline` explicitly, you can just use `span` instead of `p`.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/567Hg/)

Comment: And what happens if you want to have more than the `.same` paragraph within the `top` div? :)

Comment: @Nicolae Olariu : Then there will be another solution.) I am just sticking to the context, your know, issue illustration points this out quite clear. If OP wants something else, he can comment here or update the post, so problem could be specified better.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in following way.

```
.top
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
}
.same
{
    position: absolute;

    height: 50%; /* This is mandatory i.e. this should not be auto */
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%; /*This is not mandatory*/

    /* The code below is required to horizontally and vertically center the <p> element */
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```